# Ignored questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I made this question, because it is a real concern for me, and perhaps for others like me! It conceivably stems from lack of true understanding of the unspoken rules or behavioral constraints here on Stack Overflow. Thus, I sincerely appreciate your answers, especially from senior members.

Sometimes, when I post a question here it is not answered or commented and even not viewed that much! Why is that?!

Is it because the question is so 'stupid' and 'trivial' for the community, or maybe weakly articulated?!

Does it have anything with the reputation of the questioner, or the record of her previous questions/answers/feedback/votes?!

Is there any unspoken rule here to observe? (I am aware that there are bunch of tips in the [help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/))

Comment: This should be in meta

Comment: well, my ignored question was posted in stackoverflow, and thus, I though it would be better to ask it from the same community

Comment: StackOverflow is a site about programming.  Your question is about the site, not about programming.  meta-stackoverflow is a community for that: questions about stack overflow.  Since you don't know this I assume you haven't read the rules.  You should probably do that.

Comment: Those 'programmers' whom I asked my question are here, not in meta. I'd like to know what is in 'their' mind.

Comment: Well, that's just not how it works.

Comment: @deeep questions about programming go on Stack Overflow, questions about Stack Overflow go on the meta.  If the people wish to answer, they will, only if they choose to.

Comment: You currently have two questions on Stack Overflow. You've accepted answers to both of them. What is your actual problem?

Comment: All my questions on StackOverflow have been ignored.Other questions I ask on small sites are answered.

Answer (score 3):

> Sometimes, when I post a question here it is not answered or commented and even not viewed that much! Why is that?!
>
> Is it because the question is so 'stupid' and 'trivial' for the community, or maybe weakly articulated?!

This is known as [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality), and [it isn't new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31253/175248).

To be fair though, a few conditions of the question have to be met:

- It has to be sufficiently complex; that is, nothing that a few seconds of Googling or reading the docs can't reasonably answer or be expounded upon
- It has to be clear, concise, and a reasonably practical question to phrase
- It has to be in well in the bounds of what is an on-topic question here

This isn't a solved problem, since finding experts that can actually answer the question you have for *this* specific framework and *this* specific use case is like finding a needle in a haystack blindfolded with only your pinky toe.

The strictest definition of a question that isn't worth answering is a question that is off-topic.  Everything else is fair game, although some questions are obviously less favored than others; that is, those with a lower vote count would make less practical sense to answer as opposed to those with a higher vote count.

In those scenarios, adding a bounty would help boost the visibility of the question for a time, so that may be an option if you find yourself stuck in this rut.

> Does it have anything with the reputation of the questioner, or the record of her previous questions/answers/feedback/votes?!

Nope.  Well, it shouldn't anyway.  In programming terms, each question as presented to a potential answerer is atomic; it is an entity unto itself.  Except by the system for reasons of spam and moderation, no past question is an indicator for a future question.

> Is there any unspoken rule here to observe?

None that I'm aware of.  Perhaps there aren't enough eyeballs looking at your question, and it's as simple as that.  Bounties are probably the most viable option to address *that* portion, but there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you question ain't well described or contains no details. Without these details it might be hard to understand the question itself.

- Try to provide as much information as you can.
- Try to describe what have you done to solve that problem.
- Try to google your problem. Most likely it's already solved.

Here you can find slice of advice of how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: - Try to remove the irrelevant parts.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about others here, but:

- I don't look at the reputation of a questioner, so I wouldn't decline to answer just because a questioner had low reputation
- There are plenty of "trivial" questions that are fine, and I'm happy to answer them
- Big, long, complicated questions are usually too much work to figure out and answer, so I usually won't
- Obvious homework questions don't deserve answering, so I won't
- There are plenty of other ways that questions can be lame or annoying or otherwise not worth answering

Comment: "There are plenty of other ways that questions can be lame or annoying or otherwise not worth answering" why didn't this logic apply here?

Comment: @apaul34208: Do you mean, "Why didn't I decide that deeep's question was lame, and decide not to answer it?"